# Images folder in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

What's the way to add custom images/icons in WinForms application.
I added a folder (right-click project and add new folder) named it then as my images folder and I would like to use this folder as my main images folder.

I don't see any option to use my 'images' folder in Visual Studio after dropping the Picture Box control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the image as an embedded resource.  You can the set the `PictureBox`'s `Image` property to the resource via the property editor or at runtime by accessing the `Properties.Resources` object.  The images will be compiled directly into your executable, you just need to add them to your project.

Comment: Can you explain how to add my images as embedded resource?

Comment: File add and set it’s property “Build Action” to “Embedded Resource”

Comment: Yep, just Add -> Existing File and update the Build Action as orn pointed out.